# Angularjs: automatically update date diff?

Tags: angularjs

I'm using angular 1.6.1 and I would like to update date diff automatically.

Here is the service that calculate date diff

```
angular.module("utils", [])
.service('utils', function ($location) {

    this.correctDate = function(date) {
        var s = date.replace('T', ' ');
        return s.replace('.000Z', ' ');
    }

    this.dateDiff = function(date) {
        var oneMinute = 60*1000;
        var oneHour = 60*60*1000;
        var oneDay = 24*60*60*1000;
        var oneWeek = 24*60*60*1000*7;
        var oneMonth = 24*60*60*1000*30;
        var now = new Date();
        var d = new Date(date);
        var tNow = now.getTime();
        var tDate = d.getTime();
        if((tNow - tDate) / oneMonth >= 1){
            return Math.floor((tNow - tDate) / oneMonth) + " months";
        }
        if((tNow - tDate) / oneDay >= 1){
            return Math.floor((tNow - tDate) / oneDay) + " days";
        }
        if((tNow - tDate) / oneHour >= 1){
            return Math.floor((tNow - tDate) / oneHour) + " hours";
        }
        if((tNow - tDate) / oneMinute >= 1){
            return Math.floor((tNow - tDate) / oneMinute) + " minutes";
        }
        return "now";
    }
})
```

Here is the view

```
<div class="post__date">
    <time class="published">
        {{dateDiff(correctDate(article.createdAt))}}
    </time>
</div>
```

Now date diff is updated only if I make a click anywhere in app and I even don't understand why. So I have 2 questions :

**1) Why does date diff is updated everytime I click anywhere in my angular app ? (Does angular trigger a full digest everytime I click anywhere in app ?)**

**2) How to update automatically date diff ?**

Comment: Bind a variable instead of a function. When do you want to update the date diff? What do you even mean with automatically? `$interval(function(){$scope.dateDiff = util.dateDiff(correctDate(article.createdAt)), 5000  });` Automatic enough?

Comment: @ippi automatically like on facebook where post date are constantly updated

Comment: Ah, then an interval doesn't seem too horrible, once a minute thing perhaps.

Comment: Yes and I hope this way will not slow down my application